# Serve pdf as static resource from spring application running in docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, pdf

The **Pdf file is blank** when I try to open to it from localhost/pdfs/filename.pdf, but when I do that for the picture it works (localhost/images/imagename.png)
My app is running inside a docker container.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/pdfs/").setCachePeriod(31556926);

   }
}
```

Both folders, images and pdfs, are inside `src/main/resources/static` folder.

Why does it work for the image file but it doesn't work for pdf file?
Thanks.

Comment: For me it is strange the notation "classpath:" for serving static resources in a web application. In fact Spring Boot serves them without any extra configuration. Did you check in your browser developer tools what is the response code and the content type in the network tab when you request the pdf?

Comment: Code is 304 and the content type is pdf. The response is x��\�r�6���...

Comment: Could you please clear your browser cache and do the above again?

Comment: Carlos thanks but i already tried that and got the same result.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - it was caused by maven filtering the resources. Excluding *.pdf helped solve the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue with gradle. For me it was breaking images and pdf files. Adding a file filter resolved my issue similar to what @scalkyo did with maven.